# Best way to iterate using for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm looking for the best way to iterate in `R`. I know simple solutions like:

```
times <- 3
for(i in 1:times){

}
```

BUT if times <- 0, then my loop iterates twice, not zero. So the solution is:

```
for(i in seq_len(times))
```

So if I want to iterate from `start` to `end` :

```
for(i in seq_len(end - start))
```

BUT if `end-start < 0` then:

```
seq_len(-1)
Error in seq_len(-1) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
```

I know that I can check if `end-start < 0` before loop, but this is not very clean solution... any other ideas?

To clarify - I'm looking for solution similar to other programming languages, like C++/Java:

```
for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
```

So if `start=5` and `end=3` the loop doesn't even start.

Comment: If you are iterating over an object itself you could use `seq_along`.  Does that address your problem?

Comment: Without more of an example it is hard to tell what makes sense - what does this loop do? However, you could do `abs(end-start)` in your `for` which is the absolute value (not negative) - does that help?

Comment: Not really. `seq_along` doesn't work, I have range, not object. I've edited the question :)

Comment: Why down-vote? What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your own helper function

```
loop_seq <- function(start,end) {
    if(end<start) return(integer(0))
    seq(start, end)
}

for(i in loop_seq(3,4)) {print(i)}
# [1] 3
# [1] 4
for(i in loop_seq(3,3)) {print(i)}
# [1] 3
for(i in loop_seq(3,2)) {print(i)}
# {nothing}
```

The for loop will always iterate over a vector, so the problem really isn't the for loop, it's creating the right vector of indexes (`:`,`seq_len`, `seq_along`) that you need to worry about.

Comment: Yeah, I came up with the same idea on the subway :)

Answer (score 1):

Given your example above (C++/Java) you are essentially looking at a `while` loop.

To replicate you example:

```
start = 5
end = 3
i <- start

while(i <= end){
  print(i)
  i = i+1
}
```

This loop will not start.  Note the `<=` given that R is base-1 indexed.  Of course you could just modify the indices but this is cleaner.

Comment: @bartektartanus, understandable but I believe R `for` loops are always going to run at least once unless you provide a condition beforehand.  Naturally I would like to be proven wrong by one of the R masters around here if such a thing is possible.

Comment: I can prove this :) Just check this two examples:
`for(i in integer(0)){print(i)}` 
doesnt print anything, but this one do
`for(i in integer(1)){print(i)}`

Comment: @bartektartanus, very interesting.  I had not considered the 0 integer but I believe that may be the only exception.  To my knowledge there is no way of making the for loop not run if the iterator is less than the 'end' iterator without an additional condition.